# HTML Form Organized in Rows

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to prepare an html form that requires a layout into up to 4 distinct rows. See code below with notes. Basically, I am looking for the first 3 form items to be on row 1. The next 3 on row 2, etc. Each item should be spread out from the others. I used 3 column sizing since each text box is expecting relatively short input (one word).

Boxes 3 through 8 (rows 2 and 3) are toggled on and off depending on the select option. If toggled off, there are only 2 rows (first 3 items = row 1, button = row 2).

When I add class="row", the form items mash up against each other and when type 2 is selected, it gets even more out of whack since 6 additional boxes are added to the mess.

Using bootstrap 4

Is the row class in the correct place? Is there another class i should use? 
I am new to all this, so any help on getting this form set up to the right specs would be appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#conj").hide();
        $("#type").on("change", function() {
            if ($(this).val() === "addl") {
                $("#conj").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#conj").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<h1 align="left">Dev Env - Test 110319C</h1>
<form action="/addvocab" method="post" class="form-inline">

    <!-- Box 1, box 2 and select menu on row 1 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box1" placeholder="Box 1" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="box2" placeholder="Box 2" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <select id="type" class="form-control" name="part">
                <option disabled selected value="">Type</option>
                <option>Type 1</option>
                <option value="addl">Type 2</option>
                <option>Type 3</option>
                <option>Type 4</option>
                <option>Type 5</option>
                <option>Type 6</option>
                <option>Type 7</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>

        <!-- Boxes 3 through 8 only show if select option TYpe 2 is selected -->
        <label id="conj">

            <!-- Boxes 3, 4 and 5 on row 2 if visible -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box3" placeholder="Box 3" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box4" placeholder="Box 4" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box5" placeholder="Box 5" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Boxes 6, 7 and 8 on row 3 if visible -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box6" placeholder="Box 6" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box7" placeholder="Box 7" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box8" placeholder="Box 8" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- Button on row 2 if boxes 3 through 8 are not visible. On row 4 if visible -->
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-6" type="submit">Add Word</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your javascript code, the problem are the bootstrap tags. Several changes can solve your problem:
1. don't use form-inline class. just form class would do.
2. change label tag into div tag with the same id.
3. for the button add word placement, you forgot to put it between col tags.

[this will happen if type 2 is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmfU6.jpg)

```
    <h1 align="left">Dev Env - Test 110319C</h1>


<form action="/addvocab" method="post" class='form'>
    <!-- Box 1, box 2 and select menu on row 1 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box1" placeholder="Box 1" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="box2" placeholder="Box 2" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <select id="type" class="form-control" name="part">
                <option disabled selected value="">Type</option>
                <option>Type 1</option>
                <option value="addl">Type 2</option>
                <option>Type 3</option>
                <option>Type 4</option>
                <option>Type 5</option>
                <option>Type 6</option>
                <option>Type 7</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>

        <!-- Boxes 3 through 8 only show if select option TYpe 2 is selected -->

            <!-- Boxes 3, 4 and 5 on row 2 if visible -->
            <div id='conj'>

            <div class="row ">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box3" placeholder="Box 3" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box4" placeholder="Box 4" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box5" placeholder="Box 5" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Boxes 6, 7 and 8 on row 3 if visible -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box6" placeholder="Box 6" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box7" placeholder="Box 7" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box8" placeholder="Box 8" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button on row 2 if boxes 3 through 8 are not visible. On row 4 if visible -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-6" type="submit">Add Word</button>
    </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you very much. I now see the errors. Once I made your suggested changes, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes to your code. I hope it helps

```
<h1 align="left">Dev Env - Test 110319C</h1>
<form action="/addvocab" method="post" class="">

    <!-- Box 1, box 2 and select menu on row 1 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box1" placeholder="Box 1" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="box2" placeholder="Box 2" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <select id="type" class="form-control" name="part">
                <option disabled selected value="">Type</option>
                <option>Type 1</option>
                <option value="addl">Type 2</option>
                <option>Type 3</option>
                <option>Type 4</option>
                <option>Type 5</option>
                <option>Type 6</option>
                <option>Type 7</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Boxes 3 through 8 only show if select option TYpe 2 is selected -->
<!--        <label id="conj">-->

            <!-- Boxes 3, 4 and 5 on row 2 if visible -->
<!--             <div class=""> -->
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box3" placeholder="Box 3" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box4" placeholder="Box 4" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box5" placeholder="Box 5" type="text">
                </div>
<!--             </div> -->


            <!-- Boxes 6, 7 and 8 on row 3 if visible -->
<!--             <div class="col-12"> -->
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box6" placeholder="Box 6" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box7" placeholder="Box 7" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="box8" placeholder="Box 8" type="text">
                </div>
<!--             </div> -->

<!--        </label>-->
    </div>

    <!-- Button on row 2 if boxes 3 through 8 are not visible. On row 4 if visible -->
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-6" type="submit">Add Word</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Once I made some changes, the html worked well.